# Kotlin @JvmInline class broke class method names

Tags: kotlin

Faced with issue when using Kotlin value class annotated by ***@JvmInline***

Here is an example:

```
@JvmInline
value class TestClass(val id: String)

interface TestInterface {

  fun doSomething(aVal: TestClass)

  fun callSomething(aVal: String)
}

fun main() {
  val clazz = TestInterface::class.java
  clazz.methods.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Result output:

```
public abstract void TestInterface.callSomething(java.lang.String)
public abstract void TestInterface.doSomething-Qkb7kKY(java.lang.String)
```

Expected output:

```
public abstract void TestInterface.callSomething(java.lang.String)
public abstract void TestInterface.doSomething(java.lang.String)
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue without switching to ***data class***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Value classes do not exist at runtime**.

As you've seen from your output, the signature of your method is `TestInterface.doSomething-Qkb7kKY(java.lang.String)`. Since value classes are essentially a runtime wrapper for their value, the true signature of the method has one String parameter. On compile time, it would be perfectly okay to add another overload to this method with a single `String` parameter, on runtime, **this would cause a clash**. Let's expand on your example;

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class TestClass(val id: String)

interface TestInterface {
    fun doSomething(aVal: TestClass)
    fun doSomething(aVal: String)
    fun callSomething(aVal: String)
}

fun main() {
    val clazz = TestInterface::class.java
    clazz.methods.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

The output for the above would be the following and would therefore clash if it had the same name;

```
public abstract void TestInterface.callSomething(java.lang.String)
public abstract void TestInterface.doSomething(java.lang.String)
public abstract void TestInterface.doSomething-Qkb7kKY(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Thanks! You a right this will cause a clash